# Node-ipc in Typescript class

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, node-ipc

I am trying to use `node-ipc` in my TypeScript project and stuck on getting correct type for class member:

```
import { IPC } from 'node-ipc';

class IpcImpl extends IIpc {
    ipcSocketPath?: string;
    ipc?: any;  // What the type should be here?


    setupIpc(ipcSocketPath: string) {
        this.ipcSocketPath = ipcSocketPath;
        this.ipc = new IPC();  // Here instantiated ok, but type mismatch ed

    }
```

I of course installed `@types/node-ipc` but it doesn't helped me. I tried to specify following (everything incorrect):

- `ipc?: IPC`
- `ipc?: typeof IPC`

How to specify type of my `ipc` class member right?

Comment: what kind of error you get on `ipc?: IPC`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the node-ipc's index.d.ts content, you can not use the `NodeIPC` namespace or `NodeIPC.IPC` class directly as they are not exported:

```
declare namespace NodeIPC {
    class IPC {
        // Some methods
    }
    // Some other classes
}

declare const RootIPC: NodeIPC.IPC & { IPC: new () => NodeIPC.IPC };

export = RootIPC;
```

But, if you are using TypeScript **2.8+**, you should be able to infer the type thanks to the **conditional types** and the **type inference** using in your case:

`type InferType<T> = T extends new () => infer U ? U : undefined;`

And so you can get the `NodeIPC.IPC` type:

```
import { IPC } from 'node-ipc';

type InferType<T> = T extends new () => infer U ? U : undefined;

class IpcImpl {

    ipcSocketPath?: string;
    ipc?: InferType<typeof IPC>;

    setupIpc(ipcSocketPath: string) {
        this.ipcSocketPath = ipcSocketPath;
        this.ipc = new IPC();
    }

}
```

You can find some interresting information about the conditional types and type inference in the TypeScript 2.8 release notes:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html

**Update:**

I just found out that TypeScripts's 2.8+ includes the `InstanceType<T>` predefined conditional type which does exactly the same thing than the `InferType<T>` from my code above.
So in fact, use it directly and we have an even shorter solution:

```
class IpcImpl {

    ipcSocketPath?: string;
    ipc?: InstanceType<typeof IPC>;

    setupIpc(ipcSocketPath: string) {
        this.ipcSocketPath = ipcSocketPath;
        this.ipc = new IPC();
    }

}
```